# 2nd GPU Hashrate Low - EVGA OC, Claymore, or Something Else

Tags: ethereum, pci-e, mining

I am running the following setup:

1. Asrock 970 Extreme3 Motherboard
2. EVGA 850 Watt Titanium Power Supply
3. EVGA 1060 GTX in PCI-E x16 Slot (x16 Mode)
4. EVGA 1060 GTX in PCI-E x16 Slot (x4 Mode)
5. Claymore Dual Miner

Using EVGA OC, I have the Power set to 50% and Memory overclock at +750 which yields 22-22.5 Mh/s for ETH (and a fan speed around 20%/temp of 64-67c) on GPU 1.

On the second card in the x4 slot, it has the same EVGA settings but is only giving 15 Mh/s. It does a stock 19.5 with power at 100%. Only with power reduced does it drop low. GPU 1 has the same power settings but is in the x16 (x16 mode slot) and is producing 22 Mh/s.

If I don't use the EVGA OC but leave them at default/stock, Claymore reports them both at 19 Mh/s in their stock form.

What I am wondering is why when using EVGA OC with the same settings for both cards, why the 2nd one is over 7 Mh/s slower.

Could this be a Claymore issue? I thought about the MB Bios, but when I leave them both in stock form, they are equal... which makes me wonder if it's something weird with EVGA OC. I tried switching the primary VGA device from PCI-E to PCI in the Bios and no changes.

Any ideas of how to fix this so that Claymore sees them as running equal at 22 MH/s (which is what GPU 1 does using the same EVGA OC settings as GPU2)?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, every time that you use different PCIe port slot, you need configure it on the motherboard on the DMI/OPI x4 as a Gen 2, because on your PEG port PCIe x16 is on Gen2 or Auto.

This is a common mistake when connect two GPUs on different kind of ports PCIe (x16 and x4).

This happened to me when I connect one GPU AMD RX580 on port PCIe x1 gives me 29Mh/s, and when I connect the same card on port PCIe x16 only gives me 12Mh/s. So, I go to the MOBO menu, and the port CPIe x16 was on Auto; after change it, both PCIe slots gives me 29Mh/s.